# How can I turn a cosmosdb list of documents into a hashmap and append values to it

Tags: hashmap, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am currently trying to turn my list of documents I am getting from a cosmosdb query into a map so that I can iterate over the objects elements without using their ids. I want to remove some elements, and I want to append some data to elements as well. Finally I want to output a Json file with this data. How can I do this?

For example:

```
{
    "action": "A",
    "id": "138",
    "validate": "yes",
    "BaseVehicle": {
        "id": "105"
    },
    "Qty": {
        "value": "1"
    },
    "PartType": {
        "id": "8852"
    },
    "BatchNumber": 0,
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1551998460
}

Should Look something like this:

  "type": "App",
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "Qty": {
        "values": [
          {
            "source": "internal",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "BaseVehicle": {
        "values": [
          {
            "source": "internal",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "value": "105"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PartType": {
        "values": [
          {
            "source": "internal",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "value": "8852"
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to query data from cosmosDB, how to transform JSON or how to write JSON to a file? What did you try? Where did you get stuck? 
Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in Azure Data Factory to implement your requirements.

1.Write an API to query data from cosmos db and process data into the format you want using code.

2.Output the desired results and configure http connector as source of copy activity.Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http).

3.Configure Azure Blob Storage as sink of copy activity.The [dataset properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#dataset-properties) supports JSON format.Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage).

Comment: This isn't quite what im looking for, I can show you what I have so far

cosmoQuery q = new cosmoQuery();
cosmoResults = q.QueryClient(database, collection);

`for (Document result : cosmoResults) {
            for (String field : fieldtoRemove) {
                result.remove(field);
            }
            JsonObject entity;
            //ToDo add locale and source data to values
            
        }`